# zsh: permission denied in terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh

If I try to open a file in `% /Volumes/Samsung\ SSD/Development/` from the terminal in VS Code it works fine but if I do the same from iTerm I get `zsh: permission denied`. Let's say it is a permission issue, why then am I able to access it with VS Code but not with iTerm?

I've been struggling with this for a couple of hours already and don't know what else to do. :/

Comment: How exactly are you trying to open the file in each case?

Comment: From VS Code terminal I can run a file in `/Volumes/Samsung\ SSD/Development/`, node myFile.js and I get a result but if I go to iTerm and try to cd to `/Volumes/Samsung\ SSD/Development/`, I get `zsh: permission denied`

Comment: What does `ls -ld /Volumes/Samsung\ SSD/Development` tell you?

Comment: @user1934428, `drwxr-xr-x  17 labanino  staff  578 Sep 13 11:16 /Volumes/Samsung SSD/Development`

Comment: And, to make it clear, a `cd /Volumes/Samsung\ SSD/Development` gives _permission denied_, while a `cd` to any other directory works?

Comment: @user1934428, Oh wow, no idea what happened but it's working now! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

One way this error can happen is if you paste a copy command that contains a line break. You get a usage error from the `cp`, then a `permission denied` error from trying to execute a nonexecutable directory.

```
$ cp my_file .json
~/my_directory/

usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-aclpsvXx] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-aclpsvXx] source_file ... target_directory
zsh: permission denied: /Users/me/my_directory/
```